# SSIS Stops at a Particular Record Count

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have done 2 basic data transformations using ssis 2012 on sql 2008, one of which is giving me problems.

The scenario is that as a source I have an odbc link to some data files and as a destination am using sql native 11.

The 2 problems I have are;

a) if the destination table is set as fast load, speed is good but stops at 11989 records

b) if destiantion table is set as table/view, it takes a very long time to complete on large tables.

Comment: When it stops, does it display any relevant messages in the Output window?

Comment: I'M SURE IT DISPLAYS ERROR MESSAGES IN ALL CAPS

Comment: What is special about the record it stops on?

Comment: The load is faster on fast load because because it uses bulk insert and minimally logged. Table or view inserts one record at a time and is logged. You should always use fast load unless there's a very, very compelling reason not to.